# Error 49.4c02 on HP 4730mfp

Tags: printer, firmware, hp-laserjet

Our printer HP Color Laserjet 4730mfp just started giving the error 49.4C02.

I cleared the printer queue to make sure there weren't any mixed media sizes.
I rebooted the printer server.
I used the HP firmware update utility to update the firmware on the existing machine. This did not work.

What other way can I update the firmware? The firmware comes in a .rfu file and the printer is stuck on the error message.

Thanks

Comment: Try removing and re-installing the printer on the print server...

Comment: @B.Ng As a courtousy if you solved it yourself, like you answer, you can mark your answer as the answer. This lets others know its been resolved :)

Comment: I actually have to wait 18 hours before I can accept my own answer. Only 2 more hours to go :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up clearing the print queue, unplugging the ethernet cable, power cycling the printer, plugging the ethernet cable bug in and then updating the firmware via the ftp. After another power cycle, the printer was back to normal. Turns out it's a known issue and a firmware update is the way to go.

However, another error message 49.4c06 showed up now. The funny thing was, when I disconnected the ethernet cable then the printer would be fine and go to a Ready state. The issue would happen only when the ethernet cable was plugged in.

So, I ended up:
Disconnecting the printer from the network or computer, Removing jobs in the print queue on the server so nothing is trying to print to the printer, Installing and using different device drivers e.g. pcl5, pcl6, postscript, etc, Restarting the print server, Upgrading the firmware

None of these worked by the way.

I reached out for help where:
We accessed the admin portal of the printer in question via Google chrome, We disabled the IPX/SPX and AppleTalk features, We set an Access Control List with the print server's i.p. address, Rebooted the printer

It looks like somehow there was a backlog in the queue. Maybe some i.p. addresses were printing directly to the printer and skipping the print server. Setting the ACL and disabling the protocols seems to have fixed it. What do you guys think about this? I want to get more understanding into this issue.

Thanks